# UITextField limit the number and type of characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have two text fields that I would like to limit the number and type of characters.  I have used the following bits of code to do each function separately but cannot find a way to do both within the same function.

To restrict the type of character:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // Only characters in the NSCharacterSet you choose will insertable.
    NSCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefgABCDEFG"] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

and to limit the number of characters:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
 if (textField.text.length >= 10 && range.length == 0)
 return NO;
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.text.length >= 10 && range.length == 0)
       return NO;
    // Only characters in the NSCharacterSet you choose will insertable.
    NSCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefgABCDEFG"] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

---

**Edited**

If you want to add different condition for third text field then you can do like this.
Create the reference for 3rd text fild say `thirdField`

then use this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == thirdField) {
        //your contion e.g
        if (textField.text.length < 7) {
            return YES;
        } else {
            return NO;
        }        
    }
    else {
        if (textField.text.length >= 10 && range.length == 0)
            return NO;
        // Only characters in the NSCharacterSet you choose will insertable.
        NSCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefgABCDEFG"] invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
    }
}
```

Comment: If I added a third text field but wanted to apply different conditions to it, how would I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one of the cleanest approaches to restricting characters entered in a UITextField.  This approach allows the use of multiple predefined NSCharacterSets.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSMutableCharacterSet *allowedCharacters = [NSMutableCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
    [allowedCharacters formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    [allowedCharacters formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];
    [allowedCharacters addCharactersInString:@":./"];  //allow arbitrary characters

    if([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:allowedCharacters.invertedSet].location == NSNotFound){

        return YES;

    }

    return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way:

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        // Only characters in the NSCharacterSet you choose will insertable.
        NSCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefgABCDEFG"] invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        bool cond1 = [string isEqualToString:filtered];

     if (textField.text.length >= 10 && range.length == 0){
          return NO;
     }else{
          return (cond1);
     }

    }
```

Comment: I quickly wrote that, but the idea is to check that both conditions are OK

Comment: `if (cond1) return YES; else return NO` -- why not just `return (cond1)` ? It'll always puzzle me.